# Wireless Connection stays disconnected even after multiple attempts to fix it in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: networking, wireless, network-manager

I am new to Ubuntu, days old, so I'm pretty much clueless to most of the programming. I have been trying to set up my wireless network but nothing seems to work. For additional information I have a G750JM laptop. I installed the driver from `Additional Drivers` in `Software & Updates`. 
I used the command `lspci` to check my Network controller and got

```
Broadcom Limited BCM4352 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter (rev 03)
```

but when I check the connection in `iwconfig`

```
lo        no wireless extensions.

enp4s0    no wireless extensions.
```

I get this output.
The I followed this video 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nlLS8d4Z09c
and that didn't help. 
Next i found the command `service network-manager restart` that i found in `askUbuntu`. The network shows life by saying the the wireless network is disconnected and seems to try to reconnect but doesn't. I followed a few more instructions on Ask Ubuntu, those didn't help either, even though they were expertly written and easy to follow.

that's one
[Installing Broadcom Wireless Drivers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers?page=1&tab=votes#tab-top)

the command `nmcli dev`gives output

```
enp4s0  ethernet  connected  Wired connection 1 
lo      loopback  unmanaged  --
```

when I use the command `sudo lshw -C network` I get the output

```
*-network UNCLAIMED     
       description: Network controller
       product: BCM4352 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Broadcom Limited
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       version: 03
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:eda00000-eda07fff memory:ed800000-ed9fffff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: QCA8171 Gigabit Ethernet
       vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
       logical name: enp4s0
       version: 10
       serial: 40:16:7e:0e:87:0f
       size: 1Gbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm pciexpress msi msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=alx duplex=full ip=192.168.0.3 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=1Gbit/s
       resources: irq:33 memory:edb00000-edb3ffff ioport:d000(size=128)
```

I then used the first answer in this question
[How to install software or upgrade from an old unsupported release?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-an-old-unsupported-release)

```
Reading package lists... Done
W: The repository 'http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: The repository 'http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: The repository 'http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: The repository 'http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: Failed to fetch http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial/multiverse/source/Sources  404  Not Found
E: Failed to fetch http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-updates/multiverse/source/Sources  404  Not Found
E: Failed to fetch http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-backports/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found
E: Failed to fetch http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-security/multiverse/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Then I used the second answer and nothing either.

My question is, how to I make sure that My wireless networks, and stays working?

Thank you for reading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had many wireless problems on my older HP laptop.Finally gave up and disabled internal card(some kind of combo bluetooth/wifi card).Now using TP -Link dongle,and it works fine.This is not a solution if you need bluetooth,unless you can find a dongle that does that.This one does not have linux drivers available,but it still works,right out of the box,without installing any new drivers.Hope this helps.

Comment: I'll keep that in mind but I am hoping to code my way out of this mess. If not now, eventually I will figure it out and post the answer. I gave up on this venture for now and am using an ethernet cable.

Comment: necessity required me to get a dongle, it worked within seconds. Kinda disappointed I couldn't get a coding solution, but this will have to work, thank you.